# Center content of a minipage inside of a longtabu

Tags: horizontal-alignment, minipage

How do you center the content of a minipage that is placed inside of a longtabu?

My minipage looks like this and can be found online [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5449fd5cedfa21dd65c8b7de):

```
\begin{minipage}{0.3cm}\tiny{\textbf{T\\e\\x\\t}}\end{minipage}
```

Here is an image of the problem. I want the letteres to be centered and not left aligned.
[image]

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,twoside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1.2}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}X[c]}
\begin{longtabu}{| p{4.2cm} | X[c] | g | g | X[c] | X[c] | g | g | X[c] | X[c] | g | g |}
    \hline \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\large{Arkitekturvægtning af \textit{use case} 3, 4 og 5}}\\
    \hline \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\textbf{Kvalitetsattribut}\end{minipage}}          &   
    \multirow{2}{*}{
        \begin{minipage}{0.3cm}
            \tiny\textbf{V\\æ\\g\\t}
        \end{minipage}}   
    & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{ED}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{BP\textsubscript{DDG}}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{AED}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{BP\textsubscript{LDS}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{S}}}      \\
     \cline{3-12} & & \tiny Point & \tiny Score &  \tiny Point & \tiny Score &  \tiny Point & \tiny Score &  \tiny Point & \tiny Score &  \tiny Point & \tiny Score\\
     \tabucline[1.3pt]{-}

\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: why use a `minipage` here and have to assign a length such as `.3cm` as opposed to simply using `\centering` to centre the letters in the table cell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a nested `minipage` or `tabular` just use `\centering` within the existing specified width of the column. I also removed all left hand rule from `\multicolumn` (you should only use left hand rules in the first column, otherwise rules from multicolumn will not line up with rules in the main table preamble. I also hid the width of `Score` and `Point` so they bled into the column padding and so remained centred rather than being over-full and sticking out on the right,

[image]

```
\documentclass[danish,a4paper,twoside,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fix-cm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{*}{1.2}
\checkandfixthelayout[nearest]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}X[c]}
\begin{longtabu}{| p{4.2cm} | X[c] | g | g | X[c] | X[c] | g | g | X[c] | X[c] | g | g |}
    \hline 
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{%
\large Arkitekturvægtning af \textit{use case} 3, 4 og 5}\\
    \hline 
\multirow{2}{\hsize}{\bfseries Kvalitetsattribut}          &   
   \multirow{2}{\hsize}{{\centering\tiny\bfseries
      V\endgraf æ\endgraf g\endgraf}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{ED}}}  &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{BP\textsubscript{DDG}}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{AED}}}  & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{BP\textsubscript{LDS}}}  &
 \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{S}}} \\
     \cline{3-12} & &
 \tiny \makebox[0pt]{Point} & 
\tiny \makebox[0pt]{Score} &
  \tiny \makebox[0pt]{Point} &
 \tiny \makebox[0pt]{Score} & 
 \tiny \makebox[0pt]{Point} &
 \tiny \makebox[0pt]{Score} &  
\tiny \makebox[0pt]{Point} & 
\tiny \makebox[0pt]{Score} &
  \tiny \makebox[0pt]{Point} & 
\tiny \makebox[0pt]{Score}\\
     \tabucline[1.3pt]{-}
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Brilliant effort :) Tanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

I could not edit your original codes, so I tried to build your table from the first and this is what I found. I built another table inside the part you want to be sorted vertically by having the following code:

```
\begin{tabular}{c}
V\\[-5mm]
ae\\[-5mm]
g\\[-5mm]
t
\end{tabular}
```

as you can see, a four row table inside the main table with centre aligned text will show what you want. (Before this, I never knew that I can have tables inside each others.) You may have them left or right aligned by changing `\begin{tabular}{c}` to `\begin{tabular}{l}` or `\begin{tabular}{r}`. Please note that you should work on the vertical spacing between rows of this inside table to show what you want. I chose vertical spacing of `[-5mm]` to bring the rows closer to each other. Please add the other packages to fix the language or the colour of the table as you want.

[image]

```
%pdflatex
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\setlength\extrarowheight{12pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\large{Arkitekturvægtning af \textit{use case} 3, 4 og 5}}\\[4pt]
\hline
\multirow{2}{*}[-1.5mm]{Kvalitetsattribut} & \multirow{2}{*}{
\begin{tabular}{c}
V\\[-5mm]
ae\\[-5mm]
g\\[-5mm]
t
\end{tabular}
} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BPED} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BPDDG} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{BPAED} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{BPLDS} &\multicolumn{2}{c|}{BPS}\\[6pt]
\cline{3-12}
& & Point & Score & Point & Score & Point & Score & Point & Score & Point & Score\\[4pt]
\hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: While this works outside of a table it doesn't inside. I will add a fully working copy in a second :)

Comment: Here it is: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/5449fd5cedfa21dd65c8b7de

Comment: @FireFly3000 Please add the minimum working example under your question by editing your post.

Comment: Same added to the question :)

Comment: @FireFly3000 Please take a look at my revised answer.