# How to center text in a cell of a longtabu (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, longtabu

I have a long tabu like the one defined last in this question and online [here](https://www.sharelatex.com/project/542bf9654eb5b9c772559960). It looks like this when compiled:

[image]

As you can see the "point" and "score" text is placed in the buttom right corner. How can I have them placed in center both vertical and horizontal?

```
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}

\newcolumntype{g}{>{\columncolor{Gray}}X[c]}
\begin{longtabu}{| p{4.2cm} | X[c] | g | g | X[c] | X[c] | g | g | X[c] | X[c] | g | g |}
     \hline \multicolumn{12}{|c|}{\large{Arkitekturvægtning af \textit{use case} 3, 4 og 5}}\\
     \hline \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}{3cm}\textbf{Kvalitetsattribut}\end{minipage}}          &   \multirow{2}{*}{\begin{minipage}{0.3cm}\tiny{\textbf{V\\æ\\g\\t}}\end{minipage}}   & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{ED}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{BP\textsubscript{DDG}}} & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{AED}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{BP\textsubscript{LDS}}}  & \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\cellcolor{Gray}\textbf{BP\textsubscript{S}}}      \\
     \cline{3-12} & & \tiny{Point} & \tiny{Score} &  \tiny{Point} & \tiny{Score} &  \tiny{Point} & \tiny{Score} &  \tiny{Point} & \tiny{Score} &  \tiny{Point} & \tiny{Score}\\
     \tabucline[1.3pt]{-} \begin{minipage}{4cm}\vspace{0.1cm}Intern\\netværkskommunikation\strut\end{minipage}       & 4                  & 5 & 20                             & 3 & 12                                 & 4 & 16                             & 2 & 8                           & 3 & 12\\
     \hline \begin{minipage}{4cm}\vspace{0.1cm}Ekstern\\netværkskommunikation\strut\end{minipage}      & 4                  & 5 & 20                             & 5 & 20                                 & 5 & 20                             & 5 & 20                          & 1 & 4\\
     \hline Tid for backup                      & 4                  & 5 & 20                             & 3 & 12                                 & 5 & 20                             & 2 & 8                          & 5 & 20 \\
     \hline Nedetid                             & 5                  & 5 & 25                              & 4 & 20                                  & 3 & 15                              & 3 & 15                          & 1 & 5 \\
     \hline Kodens kompleksitet                 & 3                  & 5 & 15                              & 3 & 15                                  & 3 & 15                              & 2 & 6                           & 4 & 13 \\
     \hline Forståelsen kompleksitet            & 2                  & 5 & 10                              & 5 & 10                                  & 5 & 10                              & 4 & 8                           & 4 & 8 \\
     \hline Hukommelsesforbrug                  & 5                  & 1 & 5                               & 3 & 15                                  & 5 & 25                              & 4 & 20                          & 5 & 25 \\
     \hline CPU-forbrug                         & 4                  & 5 & 20                              & 2 & 8                                   & 3 & 12                              & 2 & 8                           & 4 & 16 \\           
     \hline Overførsels-fejlrate                 & 2                  & 5 & 10                              & 5 & 10                                  & 5 & 10                              & 4 & 8                           & 2 & 4 \\
     \tabucline[1.3pt]{-}
     \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Vægtet sum}     &         \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{145}          &                \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{116}               &              \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{137}                     &               \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{101}                &                     \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{106}           \\
     \hline\caption[Kvalitetsattributter angående backup i \textit{use case} 3-5]{Vægtning at kvalitetsatributter i forhold til \textit{use case} 3-5.\label{tab:KvalitetBackup}}
\end{longtabu}
```

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: note that size commands do not take an argument `\tiny{Point}` should be `\tiny Point` the `{}` are not being taken as the argument of `\tiny` just forming a local group (which does not scope the `\tiny` command which is outside that group).

Comment: @PeterGrill That makes sense :) I have created a fully working cpoy of the example here: https://www.sharelatex.com/project/542bf9654eb5b9c772559960

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for the note about \tiny, but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Point and Score centering is explained in the answer to the other question, just note youve asked it here. Is this question still open or is it all answered now? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208631/center-content-of-a-minipage-inside-of-a-longtabu/209221?noredirect=1#comment488848_209221

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It is almost answered. I just don't know how to center the point and score text in the vertical space? I wanted to simplify the questions, so that is why I made 2 different questions. I did not expect to get half of the answer in the other question :)

Comment: @FireFly3000 you could use an `m` column but really alignment is baseline oriented so it probably works better to `\raisebox{2pt}{\makebox[0pt]{Point}}` and raise it by whatever amount looks best "by eye"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To "vertically centre" the `Point` ans `Score` headings you could use an `m` column but really alignment is baseline oriented so it probably works better to

```
\raisebox{2pt}{\makebox[0pt]{Point}}
```

and raise it by whatever amount looks best "by eye" (the `\makebox` hides the width to allow it to centre horizontally as explained in the other question).